# Как использовать DATE_FORMAT в Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Как использовать DATE_FORMAT в Drupal 8 при использовании select query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
\Drupal::database()->select->addExpression().
```

Запрос для примера:

```
\Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'spmw') 
->fields('spmw', ['id'])
->addExpression("DATE_FORMAT(created,'%H:%i')", "created")
->execute()
->fetchObject();
```